# Django El Pagination & Adding Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, pagination

I have a page that needs extra pagination data in it's body and also in the footer javascripts. (A list of image galleries are shown and hovering over them shows the various images within.) I have Django El Pagination working for the "key image" but the additional javascript required isn't added to the end of the page as expected.

I've seen the documentation on multiple paginations on one page (for multiple objects) but haven't seen anything related to multiple fragments for the same pagination.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this without rendering two separate pagination fragments but instead adding additional `<script>` blocks inline with the main `page_template` for each object as they are added. Despite jquery being at the foot of the page it seems to work fine although I would definitely prefer to see a bunch of nicely formatted `<script>` tags at the bottom instead of littered throughout.